# Why division of labor or specialization boosts productivity

Tags: international-trade, division-of-labor

The [three reasons given](http://www.econlib.org/library/Smith/smWN1.html#B.I,%20Ch.1,%20Of%20the%20Division%20of%20Labor) by Adam Smith were:

1. Increased dexterity.
2. Saving of the time which is commonly lost in passing from one species of work to another.
3. The invention of a great number of machines which facilitate and abridge labour, and enable one man to do the work of many.

What other reasons are there?